# Why can't I bind an asset once in metal?

Tags: swift, metal

It seems I have to call `RenderCommandEncoder.setFragmentTexture` on every single render pass, even if I will always bind the same texture to index 0. Why does every render pass need to perform the bindings from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Because that's the way Apple designed it. The texture tables (one for the vertex shader and one for the fragment shader) are part of the render command encoder. You create a new render command encoder for each render pass. So, you have to reassign the texture table entries as desired. Is that really such a big deal?